# How does MMA use $\varepsilon-\delta$ language to find the limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In the help document of `Reduce` function, I can find an example of using the definition of limit to find the asymptote:

```
Reduce[ForAll[M, M > 0, Exists[δ, δ > 0, 
       ForAll[y, Element[x | y, Reals] && 0 < Abs[y - x] < δ, 
         Abs[1/(y^2 - 2)] > M]]], x]
```

But how can I use $ \varepsilon-N $ or $ \varepsilon-\delta $ language to prove that the limit of this multivariate function does not exist:

```
f[x_, y_] := ArcTan[y^2/(x^2 + x^3)]
Limit[f[x, y], {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

I did it like this, but there was no real result.

```
   Reduce[ForAll[{x,y}, 0 < Sqrt[RealAbs[x]^2 + RealAbs[y]^2] < \[Delta], 
      RealAbs[f[x, y] - 0] < \[Epsilon]], \[Delta], Reals]
    Simplify[%, 0 < \[Epsilon] < 2] // ToRadicals
```

Comment: How would you do it by hand? You should be able to arrange something similar in *Mathematica*.

Comment: First, it should be Reduce[ForAll[{x, y}, 
  0 < Sqrt[RealAbs[x]^2 + RealAbs[y]^2] < \[Delta], 
  RealAbs[f[x, y] - 0] < \[Epsilon]], \[Delta], Reals] in the above. Second, Mathematica is right, outputting Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. , since the result of Limit[f[x, y], {x, y} -> {0, 0}] is Indeterminate.

Comment: Which grammar do you use? You ask a question so the question mark should end the title of your question.

Comment: @user64494 I have revised the title of my question. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a correct Mathematica code to answer the question

```
f[x_, y_] := ArcTan[y^2/(x^2 + x^3)]
Resolve[Exists[c,ForAll[\[Epsilon], \[Epsilon] > 0, Exists[\[Delta], \[Delta] > 0, 
ForAll[{x, y}, 0 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < \[Delta], 
 RealAbs[f[x, y] - c] < \[Epsilon]]]]], Reals]
```

which returns the input. Every soft has its limitations: four quantors and a complicated function  are too much for `Resolve` at the present.

Addition. This works for a simpler function:

```
g[x_, y_] := y^2/x^2
Resolve[Exists[c,ForAll[\[Epsilon], \[Epsilon] > 0,Exists[\[Delta], \[Delta] > 0, 
ForAll[{x, y}, 0 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < \[Delta], 
 RealAbs[g[x, y] - c] < \[Epsilon]]]]], Reals]
```

> False